# GraphQL tests with Playwright failing due to TS Config issues

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, graphql, playwright

I have a repo where I'm trying to run some tests using Playwright against a graphQL url.
I've configured the tests but now I am getting error that it is not able to find the environment variable that defines the environment.

The repo under question is here - https://github.com/zac11/playwright-graphql-demo

When I try to run this command `npm run test-new`, I get this

`<<< ENVIRONMENT: undefined >>>`

I've checked the code and I cannot pinpoint the issue due to which it is not able to get the correct environment.

I see that there are lot of `ts` complains about not being able to import files with `.ts` extensions, but I think the `tsconfig.json` file added should have been able to correct it. And I'm confused if this is the real issue which is making it to not recognise the code correctly.

Please suggest/point if there is any configuration issues or there is something missing in the code.

Stack trace:

```
   npm run test-new

> playwright-graphql-demo@1.0.0 test-new
> cross-env test_env=prod npx playwright test --config=playwright.config.ts --project=graphql


Running 5 tests using 1 worker

  ✘  1 [graphql] › graphql.spec.ts:16:5 › GRAPHQL DEMO › should list all teas (92ms)
<<< ENVIRONMENT: undefined >>>

<=============SENDING REQUEST==============>

 REQUEST URL: 
 

 REQUEST DATA: 
 query: { teas { id, name} }
  -  2 [graphql] › graphql.spec.ts:20:5 › GRAPHQL DEMO › should add new tea
  -  3 [graphql] › graphql.spec.ts:24:5 › GRAPHQL DEMO › should get new tea by name
  -  4 …aphql.spec.ts:28:5 › GRAPHQL DEMO › should verify that new tea is in the list of all teas
  -  5 [graphql] › graphql.spec.ts:33:5 › GRAPHQL DEMO › should delete newly added tea


  1) [graphql] › graphql.spec.ts:16:5 › GRAPHQL DEMO › should list all teas ─────────────────────

    Error: apiRequestContext.post: First argument must be either URL string or Request

       at ../helperMethods/api.helper.ts:54

      52 |     this.logRequestAPI(URL, data);
      53 |
    > 54 |     const response = await api.post(URL, { data});
         |                                ^
      55 |     const status = response.status();
      56 |     const respJson = await response.json();
      57 |   

        at GrapQLService.getAllTeas (/UserDir/playwright-graphql-demo/helperMethods/api.helper.ts:54:32)
        at /UserDir/playwright-graphql-demo/tests/graphql.spec.ts:17:9

    attachment #1: trace (application/zip) ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    test-results/graphql-GRAPHQL-DEMO-should-list-all-teas-graphql/trace.zip
    Usage:

        npx playwright show-trace test-results/graphql-GRAPHQL-DEMO-should-list-all-teas-graphql/trace.zip

    ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  1 failed
    [graphql] › graphql.spec.ts:16:5 › GRAPHQL DEMO › should list all teas ──────────────────────
  4 skipped
```

Comment: Where is the stack trace?

Comment: Added stacktrace @VishalAggarwal

Comment: "const URL = ENV.BASE_URL as string;"                                                                      
  @demouser123 What is the console print value of "ENV.BASE_URL" inside api.helper.ts?

Comment: It's printing `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to pass URL as command line argument like:

```
URL=https://playwright.dev npm run test-new
```

Comment: It works that way but that defeats the purpose of having an env file and then passing the value isn't it?

Comment: @demouser123    Ok then where are you supplying actual URL in your codebase? I couldn't find it anywhere...In your env file , I don't see any values provided..

Comment: " public static BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL
}"